# Edit Product Link in No Stock Admin Notification Email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to have an 'Edit product' link in the 'No stock' emails that the admin receives after a sale/ product is changed to out of stock.

This type of code works fine for getting all post meta/custom fields, but for post edit link it only works intermittently, really struggling to figure out what i'm doing wrong, tried various ways i know of getting edit_post and googled 100s of posts here on stack but only this one works now and then, need it to work all the time. Many thanks in advance if anyone can help..

```php
function filter_woocommerce_email_content_edit_me_link( $message, $product ) { 

    $id = $product->get_id();
    $edit_link = get_edit_post_link( $id, $product );

    $string .= '<p class="edit-this"><a href="' . get_edit_post_link() . '">Edit Product</a></p>';

    return $string;
}     

// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_content_no_stock', 'filter_woocommerce_email_content_edit_me_link', 10, 12 );
```

// by various ways i mean with message or string as per all the returns as below, with a backslash ed/edi/edit it also worked but only upon manually placing an order, not when other users place an order.

```php
//return get_edit_post_link($this->ID);
//echo get_edit_post_link($post->ID);

//return $message."\nEdit  ".$edit_link;

//return $message. " \n " .get_edit_post_link(intval($product->product_id)) .$edit_link;

 //return $edit_link. " edit\ " .get_edit_post_link(intval($product->product_id)) .$edit_link;

//return $message." \nedit " .$edit_link;

//return $message. " \ " .$edit_link;
//return $string .= ' <a href=" ' .get_edit_post_link(($product->product_id)) . '"> ' .get_edit_post_link($product->product_id) .'</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Code below works fine for admin user who places the order but if others place the order, there is no edit link in the admin no stock email..

Using the global `$product` doesn't seem to help.

```php
function filter_woocommerce_email_content_edit_me_link( $message, $product ) { 

    $id = $product->get_id();
    $edit_link = get_edit_post_link( $id, $product );

    return $message."  edit product  " .$edit_link;
}     

// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_content_no_stock','filter_woocommerce_email_content_edit_me_link', 10, 12 );
```